# Splitting field of $x^5+x+1\in\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

My problem is

> Find the splitting field, $F$, of $x^5+x+1\in\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ and determine the degree $[F:\mathbb{Z}_2]$.

I was able to factor $x^5+x+1=\left(x^2+x+1\right)\left(x^3+x^2+1\right)$ and both of the factors are irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$, I think.

Since $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a field and $x^2+x+1\in\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ is irreducible and monic, then $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]\,/\left(x^2+x+1\right)$ is a field extesion of $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Then $c:=x+\left(x^2+x+1\right)$ is a root of $x^2+x+1$ (in which field?). Similary with the other factor. But how is this helpful?

Comment: Notice that $\Bbb Z_2 [x] / (x^2 + x + 1)$ has $2^2$ elements, so it is isomorphic to $\Bbb F _{2^2}$ (because there exist a single field with $2^k$ elements, modulo an isomorphism), therefore modulo this isomorphism you may view $c$ as an element of $\Bbb F _{2^2}$. A similar analysis can be done for the other factor, which will have a root in $\Bbb F _{2^3}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the factors is irreducible because they are degree at most $3$ with no roots. Now we know that there is a root of the quadratic factor in the (unique) degree $2$ extension of $\Bbb F_2$, and similarly for the cubic factor in the degree $3$ extension. Now each of these fields is contained in the degree $6$ extension, and clearly it is the smallest degree extension which has subfields of degrees $2$ and $3$, so the splitting field is $\Bbb F_{2^6}$, the field with $2^6$ elements.

Comment: Alex M. That's cool. :D I knew, that fields with same number of elements are isomorphic, but this is smart application. But what is the degree $[F:\mathbb{Z}_2]$? Just $2^5$?

Comment: @byk hey, I'm not AlexM :-) the degree is 6, since number of elements is $2^6$ as I said in the answer write up.